# Как сделать окно google play?

Tags: java, android, view, material-design

Каким образом сделать такое окно?

1) оно должно скролиться как на картинках
2) В одной из картинок есьт Google map. Она не двигается, я такого не видел никогда. Это использовали enable=false?

P.S. Админы видите какие громозкие темы получаются из за того что картинки нельзя прятать в спойлерах. Которые как на других сайтах открываются и закрываются

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скрола на картинках не видно, как сойлеры сделать на мете написано, разметка сделана по этому шаблону: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare, а карта это MapView

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, Вы мне лучше скажите. Это все в ручную сделанно или есть готовая библиотека? Я такой дизайн вижу во всех приложениях. Но сам сделать не могу. Будто это какой то готовый фрагмент, в sdk гугла его не нашел

Comment: Сложно представить как можно ещё больше упростить. Просто координатор в котором 2 контейнера. Один сверху, другой снизу. Просто скопируйте разметку из примера и изменяйте по своему вкусу

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, спс сделал. А 2 вопрос насчет гугл карты. Как сделать чтобы она была как на картинке. тобишь есть карта но она не скролиться и не нажимается. фокус не берет на себя. Она выглядит как не карта и а, как изображение

Comment: Как я уже писал выше - это MapView. Возможно надо ей прописать liteMode. А ещё можно чрез гугловое апи просто картинку получать с местоположением

Comment: Юрий напишите как ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

разметка сделана по этому шаблону: github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare,

Кратко -  берём CoordinatorLayout c 2 детьми - AppBarLayout и контейнер для контента с прописанным `app:layoutBehaviour`

А карта это MapView с лёгким режимом (liteMode) или просто картинка полученная через гугловое апи для карт (посылаем координаты - получаем картинку-карту)